# Efficient way to split a number in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I'm struggling with finding an efficient way to split the digits of a number into a list.

For example, for the number:

```
23464646237
```

and the

```
ArrayList <Integer> vector;
```

i want to insert in each position of the array, a digit from the number, therefore obtaining the following output:

```
vector = {2,3,4,6,4,6,4,6,2,3,7}
```

How can i do this in a clean and efficient way in Java ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: @MarsAtomic it is not the same

Comment: @MarsAtomic because i'm worried about efficiency here, not just the reading part

Comment: You might want to read all those answers in detail, because there is some discussion of efficiency. Look in particular at the modulus solution. All of this munging of Strings is quick and dirty, but not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parseInt` is not needed,

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberAsString.length(); i++)
    vector.add((int)numberAsString.charAt(i) - 48);
```

This will retrieve the ASCII value of the number at the position, then subtract 48 which is the value of 0 in the table.

Number from -127 to 127 are cached so I believe this will be the most efficient method (note that I'm not 100% sure). But anyway, only tried to give a way saving the `parseInt` call as you asked for the *most* efficient.

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't convert it to string. Because it will work faster with numeric values. So you can use:

```
long nr = 23464646237;
while (nr > 0)
{
    vector.add(nr % 10);
    nr /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Last line of the loop should be simplified to `nr /= 10;`

Comment: @bmavus This won't compile, you will have an error saying that 23464646237 is too large for an integer. Change your declaration to `long nr = 23464646237l;`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Integer> vector = Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(number).split(""))
            .stream()
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make your number a string and make use of the charAt() method to add each char of the string into a List.

```
public static ArrayList<Object>vect=new ArrayList<Object>();


public static void main(String[] args){
    String y="123321312312";
    for (int i=0;i<y.length();i++){
        vect.add(y.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
long yourNumber = 23464646237L;
ArrayList<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String numStr = String.valueOf(yourNumber);
for(int i=0;i<numStr.length();i++)
{
    vector.add(Integer.valueOf(numStr.charAt(i)));
}
```

Comment: I didnt downvote, but, `numStr` is not array to go by index.

Comment: Thanks. Im getting mixed up with C++ where you can use [] to access a character at an index of a string :)

Comment: @DermotBlair This won't compile, you will have an error saying that `23464646237 ` is too large for an integer. Change your declaration to `long yourNumber = 23464646237l;`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard its updated now, thanks.